# How to call JavaScript function from Selenium RC using Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-rc

I have user-extensions.js that contain the following code of snippet:

```
Selenium.prototype.doTypeRepeated = function(locator, text) {
    // All locator-strategies are automatically handled by "findElement"
    var element = this.page().findElement(locator);

    // Create the text to type
    var valueToType = text + text;

        // Replace the element text with the new text
    this.page().replaceText(element, valueToType);
};
```

I want to call this function from java code using Selenium RC for a text field ("css=input.text"). How can I call this?

Comment: I have switched to WebDriver from Selenium RC. Method executeScript("") of JavascriptExecutor is used for using JS in Selenium2 (WebDriver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a top of my head you should be able to call your code the following way:

```
selenium.getEval("Selenium.prototype.doTypeRepeated('input.text', 'some text');");
```

However, if following [suggested](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.html) approach you should do like

```
HttpCommandProcessor proc;
proc = new HttpCommandProcessor("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "http://google.com/");
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium(proc);
string[] inputParams = {"css=input.text", "Hello World"};
proc.DoCommand("doTypeRepeated", inputParams);
```

And not forget to start selenium as

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -userExtensions user-extensions.js
```

Comment: The suggested approach is the right one.  You don't want to run the doWhatever() function directly, it won't do what you expect.